# setprecision() gives extra digits if they are zeroes

Tags: c++

I've used setprecision(8), but when I count asin(1) it returns 0.017452406 (10 digits, not 8!) What can be done there?

Comment: Use `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << asin(1);`.

Comment: It might help if you could attach your actual code snippet Maxim.

Comment: Note that "17452406" **is** eight significant digits. You could write this as 1.7452406e-2, which also has eight significant digits.

Comment: No, I need to make number (both integer and decimal parts) to be displayed in max 8 digits.

Comment: I don't understand why asin(1) is resulting in 0.017452406.  That does not seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the problem with decimal digits you need to use `std::fixed`.

As explaned in [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/)

> Sets the floatfield format flag for the str stream to fixed.
>
> When floatfield is set to fixed, floating-point values are written using fixed-point notation: the value is represented with exactly as many digits in the decimal part as specified by the precision field (precision) and with no exponent part.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your requirement from the comments: "I need to make number (both integer and decimal parts) to be displayed in max 8 digits." You could use an [`ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
        std::ostringstream ss; // declare your string stream
        ss << std::setprecision(16); // set a high precision to avoid rounding

        // Insert your float to the string stream
        float f = 0.123456789;
        ss << f;

        // Get the string from the stream
        std::string f_str = ss.str();

        // Print
        std::cout << f_str.substr(0, 8 + 1) << std::endl; // take 8 first digits
        //            Note the +1 here ^ (because of the dot)

        return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0.1234567
```